# Laravel Route for api is not working get error mesage

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5

I have a route in laravel that I'm trying to set up. I'm using **version 5.2.45**.

Here's my **route.php** file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () {

  Route::resource('prayer', 'PrayerController', [ 
    'except' => ['edit', 'create']
    ]);

  Route::resource('prayer/list', 'ListController', [ 
    'only' => ['store', 'destroy']
    ]);

  Route::post('user', [
    'uses' => 'AuthController@store'
    ]);

  Route::post('user/signin', [
    'uses' => 'AuthController@signin'
    ]);

});
```

Here's my **AuthController.php** file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      return "Request Works!";
    }

    public function signin(Request $request) 
    {
      return "It Works";
    }
}
```

So when I go to my route: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user I see this error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

in RouteCollection.php line 218

at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205

at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158

at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821

at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691

at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675

at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246

at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))

at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44

at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))

at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), 
array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))

at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))

at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103

at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132

at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99

at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

at require_once('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rosary-api/api/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Not sure what's going on here as all of my other routes work when I visit them in the browser. But in postman none of them actually work. I'm only starting out with Laravel so all help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a route in your route file that matches your request. So, you could do two things:

1. Add a resource route for User
2. Add a GET route like this:

> Route::get('user', [ 'uses' => 'AuthController@someMethod' ]);

And remember: a request from your browser is always GET.

Comment: Thanks! I did try that but for post requests with postman it doesn't work for my route...

Comment: Sure, for POST request you need a POST route ;)

Comment: To clarify--there seems to have been and issue with postman. I updated to the latest version and it worked. Also, your GET route code works!